# Numpy : check if any array in 3D array is in another shorter 3D array with duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a Numpy array like this one :

```
source = np.array([[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]])
```

And I'm trying to compare it to an other array, which has shorter Axis2 and duplicates in Axis3 :

```
values = np.array([[[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]])
```

My goal is to have an array of booleans as long as the longest :

```
[False, False,True,True,False,False,True]
```

I've tried these command :

```
np.isin(source,values).all(axis=2)
```

But it displays an array of seven True. A function like numpy.in1d() seemed to be a good option, but I've didn't achieve to adapt it for 3D arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
np.in1d(np.apply_along_axis(''.join, 2, source.astype(str)), 
        np.apply_along_axis(''.join, 2, values.astype(str)))

array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True])
```

---

Another way, though might be memory intensive:

```
(source.transpose(1,0,2) == values).all(2).any(1)
array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True])
```

Comment: Just tested, and it worked fine. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Compare each row in values with each row in source

```
result = (source[:,:,:] == values[:,:,None]).all(axis=-1).any(axis=1)[0]
```

---

Solution 2: Convert it (n,1) shape

```
source_2d = source.squeeze(0)
values_2d = values.squeeze(0)
dtype = [(f'{i}', source_2d.dtype) for i in range(source_2d.shape[1])]
source_struct = source_2d.view(dtype)
values_struct = values_2d.view(dtype)
result = np.isin(source_struct, values_struct)
print(result.squeeze(1).tolist())
```